# MySQL - how to get count of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have these data in database:

```
+----+------------+---------+
| id | col1       | col2    |
+----+------------+---------+
|  1 |          3 |       2 |
|  2 |          2 |       3 |
|  3 |          4 |       5 |
+----+------------+---------+
```

I am trying to do a query, that will give me a count of rows, in which are the same numbers.
I know the value one of them (the numbers).

In this case, the same numbers are **2** and **3** (in the columns **col1** and **col2**) - I am trying to get from database number **2** (two rows). I have available always one of two numbers - in this case number **3**.

Is possible to do this query?
Thanks for help.

Comment: so many edge cases to consider.... what if row ID 4 has `col1 = 3` and `col2 = 6`? (Still count = 2?) If Row 5 is `col1 = 6` and `col2 = 3` (That makes it count = 4?)

Answer (score 2):

For the very narrow scenario you specified, I would try this:

```
select count(*)
from myTable mt1 
     inner join myTable mt2 on (mt1.col1 = mt2.col2 AND mt2.col1 = mt1.col2)
and mt1.col1 = 3 --here goes the known value
```

This only works for the data you posted. Please let us know the count for the following scenario:

```
+----+------------+---------+
| id | col1       | col2    |
+----+------------+---------+
|  1 |          3 |       2 |
|  2 |          2 |       3 |
|  3 |          3 |       2 |
|  4 |          3 |       5 |
|  5 |          4 |       5 |
+----+------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like

```
SELECT (col1+col2) , COUNT(*) AS num_rows
FROM table1
WHERE col1 =3 OR col2 =3
GROUP BY (col1+col2)
HAVING num_rows >1
```

Answer (score 0):

With this query:

```
select count(*) count_rows
from table1 
where col1=3 or col2=3
group by concat(IF(col1<col2, col1, col2), ',', IF(col1<col2, col2, col1))
```

you get the result `2`.

Replace the `3` from the query in the where clause if there is another input.

The value for `concat(IF(col1<col2, col1, col2), ',', IF(col1<col2, col2, col1))` would be `"2,3"` for records 1-2, (and `"4,5"` for the third record).